# Bootstrap DateTimePicker in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Modal in ASP.Net with MVC 5 which I use to edit an entry on a FullCalendar javascript plugin.

_Edit.cshtml:

```
@model Models.CalendarEntry

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Calendar Entry</h4>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>@Model.Title</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CalendarEntryId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostId)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntryDateTime, htmlAttributes: new {  @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="input-group" id="datetimepicker">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EntryDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EntryDateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Length, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Length, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Length, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntryStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.EntryStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EntryStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
}
```

For some reason two things are happening that I cannot figure out why.

Firstly, the `glyphicon-calendar` does not sit next to the input:
[image: input and glyphicon]

Secondly, when the Modal Form load, all the other fields except for the datetime field gets populated with data, until I click the calendar glyphicon, then the datetime field gets populated with the current date and time. The value from the model never gets displayed.

Web interfaces are not my forté and would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

turns out, that I needed to set options for the datetimepicker, more specifically, a default value it would seem like:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker(
                {
                    defaultDate: '@Model.EntryDateTime',
                    showTodayButton: true,
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
                    showClose: true,
                    showClear: true,
                    toolbarPlacement: 'top',
                    stepping: 15
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

When you create a new MVC project, it comes with a default css file(Site.css) which has some predefined css styles in it. By default, it has input field's `max-width` defined as `280px`. That is the reason, your input groups are not working as expected.

[image]

If you remove/make adjustments to this css class in your `~/Content/Site.css`, You css problem will be resolved.

Comment: Nice! I will play around with this. I have commented out the max-width attribute and the glyphicon is now next to the input, although they now take up the whole row. I will play around with it.

Answer (score 3):

Would you try to put an attribute:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]

public DateTime EntryDateTime {get; set;}
```

and comment the JS script?

[Example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: thanks for the link, have an upvote. I had to add the [DisplayFormat] attribute to my model

Comment: ok, now it stopped working again for some reason. any idea on what else i could try? It only happens when the datepicker is activated on the input

Comment: is there any browser's errors?; F12 key to see them.

Comment: can't remember, but got it working, thanks. only annoyance is that commenting out the css max-width for the inputs, causes the input to be 100% (obviously) and the calendar glyph is right next to it. as soon as I set a size for inputs, there is a space between the glyph and the input.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick solution is to also format the date like this in your javascript:

```
defaultDate: '@Model.EntryDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")'
```

The solution of using the [DisplayFormat] as an attribute is just as valid if not a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, that is not a bad option. Lately, I have been using '.ToShortDateFormat()'. Let the server sort it out

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span col-sm-6> @Html.Label("Date of Birth", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</span>
                    <div class='input-group date col-sm-3' id='datetimepicker1'>

                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                    </span>

                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked great for me after fiddling around and searching for quite a while.